# MySQL Update using data from same table

Tags: mysql

Started off using this query to update data in the same table:

```
update INVENTORY
set billtoorg_id = 
    (
        select
                dist.BillToOrg_id
        from
                INVENTORY as inv,
                contacts as cntc,
                distributors as dist
        where
                inv.f_contact_id=cntc.contact_id
                and cntc.f_dist_id=dist.dist_id
    )
where
    f_contact_id is not null
    and f_product_id = 7
    and BillToOrg_id is null
```

I found out that this won't work because in MySQL I can't use the same table in the query that I use in Update. So, I created a sub-query (see below) but now I'm getting error that indicates that the subquery returns more then 1 row.

```
update inventory
set billtoorg_id = 
    (
        select
                BillToOrg_id
        from
            (
                SELECT
                    dist.BillToOrg_id
                from
                    inventory as inv,
                    contacts as cntc,
                    distributors as dist
                where 
                    inv.f_contact_id=cntc.contact_id
                    and cntc.f_dist_id=dist.dist_id
            ) as I2
    )
where
    f_contact_id is not null
    and `f_product_id` = 7
    and `BillToOrg_id` is null
```

Can someone suggest a way to get this done? I'm new to SQL and I'm not sure I'm constructing the whole thing properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to se the billtoorg_id to be what is in the distributors table matched through contacts table. If you are trying to update more than 1 row at a time, your technique won't work.

Try:

```
update inventory as inv inner join contacts as cntc on inv.f_contact_id= cntc.contact_id
    inner join distributors as dist on cntc.f_dist_id=dist.dist_id
set inv.billtoorg_id = dist.billtoorg_id
where
    inv.f_contact_id is not null
    and `inv.f_product_id` = 7
    and `inv.BillToOrg_id` is null
```

edited as I think inner join will be better.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you Garr. Now the fun part is to figure out why and how this works. :)